# all of my POST links are handled by "create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

im trying to make a simple search on my database from the index action instead of listing all the data

this is my users/index

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<fieldset>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5 offset3">
            <h2>Enter the CPF number of the user to be managed: </h2></br></br></br>
            <div>
                <%= label_tag :cpf_no, 'CPF Number:' ,class:"left_align" %>
                <%= number_field_tag :cpf_no, params[:cpf_no] %>
            </div>
            <div>
                <%= button_to  "     Find     ", users_find_path , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

and this is the find method in my controller:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController   
  ...
def find 
if request.post?
@user = user.find_by_cpf_no(params[:cpf_no])
redirect_to edit_user_path(@user.id)
end     
end 
...
end
```

and this are my routes now:

```
              root        /                                home#index
             login GET    /global/login(.:format)          sessions#new
                   POST   /global/login(.:format)          sessions#create
            logout DELETE /global/logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
        users_find POST   /global/users/find(.:format)     users#find
             users GET    /global/users(.:format)          users#index
                   POST   /global/users(.:format)          users#create
          new_user GET    /global/users/new(.:format)      users#new
         edit_user GET    /global/users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
              user GET    /global/users/:id(.:format)      users#show
                   PUT    /global/users/:id(.:format)      users#update
                   DELETE /global/users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
            fields GET    /global/data(.:format)           fields#index
                   POST   /global/data(.:format)           fields#create
         new_field GET    /global/data/new(.:format)       fields#new
        edit_field GET    /global/data/:id/edit(.:format)  fields#edit
             field GET    /global/data/:id(.:format)       fields#show
                   PUT    /global/data/:id(.:format)       fields#update
                   DELETE /global/data/:id(.:format)       fields#destroy
```

the problem is it doesnt go to the :id/edit path... it instead calls the create method which gives a few errors because the validations didnt pass. how do i make it access find method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the path right in your form_tag.

```
form_tag user_find_path, :method => :post
    # other code
    = submit_tag "Find"
```

Comment: lovely! it works! can u please explain why the button alone didnt work? because it was clearly pointing to the right path as well as using the right http method. routes should have taken care of it right?

Comment: Well it was posting, but just not to the right path. I think without specifying the path in the form_tag itself, it defaulted to just going to /users, and as a post, that means it goes to the create action.